# Update Managed Metadata value using REST in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm able to **update a 'normal' Metadata value** via my REST call.
I'm also trying to **update a Managed Metadata value** via the same call.

I'm getting **no errors.** 
The normal value **gets updated as as expected**, but the MMD value **stays emtpy**.

**Here's my sample Code:**

```
//DEMO URL
var url = "[...]/_api/Web/Lists(guid'nnnnnnnn-nnnn-nnnn-nnnn-nnnnnnnnnnnn')/Items(nn)";

var updateObject = {};

//MANAGED METADATA FIELD FOR SETTING
updateObject["MMD_FIELD"] = {
    "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue" },
    "Label": "nn",
    "TermGuid": "047cb946-451d-45bf-882a-52e47e97a871",
    "WssId": -1
};

//NORMAL METADATA "TEXT-FIELD" FOR SETTING
updateObject["Subject"] = "WORKS";

//FILETYPE
updateObject["__metadata"] = {'type':'SP.ListItem'};

//AJAX CALL     
$.ajax({

    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify( updateObject ),
    headers: { 
      "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose ",
      "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose ",
      "X-RequestDigest" : $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
      "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
      "If-Match": "*"
   }

});
```

After that the 'Subject' of the File is 'WORKS' - **but there's no chance to update a Managed Metadata Field.**

**Tried:**

- Some other MMD-Fields
- Defined ETag in "If-Match"
- Some other X-HTTP-Methods ( PATCH ... )
- Other Terms etc.
- GUID, Label and Name are 100% right
- Tried normal and mmd value in seperate calls

Answer (score 0):

Updating MMD (Taxonomy) fields is not possible using SharePoint REST API since there is **no support for term store** yet. You cannot query the termset and get the guid for the Term Label associated to the column.